# Sliding transition not smooth in SlidingMenu Lib Android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using Sliding Menu lib ([link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)) for getting the sliding menu like Facebook app and its really very cool.
I have integrated it into my project by using following code and its working.

```
slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
slidingMenu.setShadowWidth(80);
slidingMenu.setBehindScrollScale(0);
slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.behind_offset);
slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0);
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.popupmenu);
```

But issue is when I click on right most button to get sliding menu It slide as I want but the transition is not smooth. It start to slide stuck for fraction of seconds and again continue to slide.

So how can I use it to slide smoothly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution for my problem.

What I did is just add
 `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

in `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

So now its sliding smoothly as I wanted.

Comment: ...and if that's already done and still doesn't help? I doubt that this is the real reason. I got the same "hickup" problem but hardware acceleration is on.

Comment: I also tried this but nothing happened.It will a short time stop in the middle of the slidingmenu

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the view hosted in your "content" on "menu" area of the sliding menu is redrawing through the animation at a big cost. 
Try to "pause" its redrawings while the menu is sliding and/or optimize this redrawing.

That's, at least, the issue I had. It's likely you have the same.

Comment: Well actually. I just enabled Hardware Acceleration from code and now its sliding smoothly..

Comment: Ha ha good point. You should answer your question and validate the answer with what you've just told here then :)

Comment: How can I pause the redrawing in my menu view? All I got there is a ListView

Comment: @Thibault D Could you please help how to avoid redrawing in menu .In my menu I have placed Recyler view and activity i am calling after on click. but its getting stuck . 
but if i do showContent(false) then its not flickering but taking some time to open activity . Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ,When you want to switch ,You can use this 
   `showContent(false) or toggle(false)` which will prevent the so-called smoothly scroll and  transition immediately (It is so-called smoothly scroll that cause to lag ) .